# Warning: React does not recognize the `secondaryFill` prop on a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, react-native, font-awesome

My code in `App.js`

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome'
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { faEllipsisV } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
library.add(faEllipsisV)

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon="ellipsis-v" />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Produce following warnings:

> Warning: React does not recognize the `secondaryFill` prop on a DOM
>   element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom
>   attribute, spell it as lowercase `secondaryfill` instead. If you
>   accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM
>   element.
>       in path (created by Path)
>       in Path (created by FontAwesomeIcon)
>       in svg (created by Svg)
>       in Svg (created by FontAwesomeIcon)
>       in FontAwesomeIcon (at App.js:24)
>       in div (created by View)
>       in View (at App.js:23)
>       in div (created by View)
>       in View (at App.js:22)
>       in div (created by View)
>       in View (at App.js:21)
>       in div (created by View)
>       in View (created by ScrollView)
>       in div (created by View)
>       in View (created by ScrollViewBase)
>       in ScrollViewBase (created by ScrollView)
>       in ScrollView (at App.js:20)
>       in App (at withExpoRoot.web.js:10)
>       in ExpoRootComponent (at registerRootComponent.web.js:6)
>       in RootComponent
>       in div (created by View)
>       in View (created by AppContainer)
>       in div (created by View)
>       in View (created by AppContainer)
>       in AppContainer

and

> Warning: React does not recognize the `secondaryOpacity` prop on a DOM
>   element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom
>   attribute, spell it as lowercase `secondaryopacity` instead. If you
>   accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM
>   element.
>       in path (created by Path)
>       in Path (created by FontAwesomeIcon)
>       in svg (created by Svg)
>       in Svg (created by FontAwesomeIcon)
>       in FontAwesomeIcon (at App.js:24)
>       in div (created by View)
>       in View (at App.js:23)
>       in div (created by View)
>       in View (at App.js:22)
>       in div (created by View)
>       in View (at App.js:21)
>       in div (created by View)
>       in View (created by ScrollView)
>       in div (created by View)
>       in View (created by ScrollViewBase)
>       in ScrollViewBase (created by ScrollView)
>       in ScrollView (at App.js:20)
>       in App (at withExpoRoot.web.js:10)
>       in ExpoRootComponent (at registerRootComponent.web.js:6)
>       in RootComponent
>       in div (created by View)
>       in View (created by AppContainer)
>       in div (created by View)
>       in View (created by AppContainer)
>       in AppContainer

in my browser console.

The warnings will disappear when removing `<FontAwesomeIcon icon="ellipsis-v" />`. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Do you get the warnings if you replace the string with the imported icon version: `icon={ faEllipsisV }`?

Comment: @iamaatoh Yeah same warning exists.

Comment: same error message appears to me but it seems to be a problem with Fontawesome

Answer (score 0):

There is a [patch](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-native-fontawesome/pull/74) of the fontawesome repo someone created to address this issue.